# import or including navbar into different file pages with dynamic active nav tab

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I just want to ask if there's a way to store my navbar in one file page and dynamically change its active depending on what user will click?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Like this code, it will be stored in one page. But the home should not be active if clicked on features and features should be the active item. Because I am copying the same navbar into every pages, and changing its active depends on the file page. I want to do this to avoid redundancy, if possible. Thank you.

Comment: I don't think this is possible to achieve using raw HTML, you'd need to use PHP/JS to get the current page the user is on and based on that, adjust the class to include your additional properties that you need.

Comment: @Skully Hello, what do I search to achieve this one via JS? I genuinely don't know what is the keyword to at least get the result that is similar to my problem. Thank you.

Comment: Use window.location.pathname to get the current page and add class if href matches with the path.

Comment: @AbhishekSarwan so basically the logic should be there's a condition like "if" if the class was click, then I should trigger the window.location.pathname? and this can be done through, JavaScript right? please do correct me if I am wrong, thank you.

Comment: Essentially yes, you can simply just look at the current document URL and adjust the HTML element as required to add your '(current)' suffix to it. See my answer for how this can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Javascript to gather all of the `<a>` elements from your navbar by their class, in this case your `nav-link` class will do. With a collection of these links, we can then iterate through them and check to see which target href matches the current page the user is on, and append text to the end of it.

You can place the following code block just before your closing body tag.

```html
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        let allLinks = $(".nav-link").map(function() {
            return this; // Fetch all elements that have the .nav-link class and add them to our list.
        }).get();

        // Iterate through each of the links we fetched.
        $.each(allLinks, function(key, value) {
            if (value.href == document.URL) { // If the href attribute for this link matches the current page URL.
                $(this).html(value.innerText + " <span class='sr-only'>(current)</span>"); // Adjust the HTML of the element and append a suffix to the end, or do anything else here as required.
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help!